# What is the best encoding if the cost in Huffman tree is 2^len?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

I recently met a problem of encoding, it is very similar to the [Huffman Tree Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding): The more the item appears the shorter code we get.

But the difference is: in Huffman Coding, all cost for one type of items is **length_of_code_for_item * frequentness**, but in my requirement, the cost is **2^length_of_code_for_item * frequentness**.

Any existing coding algorithm for that??

Comment: Given that the cost is exponential in the length, I would simply take the logarithm of the frequencies, and proceed as normal with the Huffman encoding.

Comment: @user3386109 a clever thought! But does it minimum the total cost? I think it works if the total cost is the product of all costs. But here it's the sum of all costs. I can't see why it is the best coding. Did I miss something?

Comment: @user3386109 I'll take that as an experiment solution and compare it with the Huffman code. But I can't prove that's the best.

Comment: What *is* `length_of_it`: length of encoding or some other property of `it` (one `item` of `one type`?)?

Comment: @JeffLi Yes, it is an experimental solution. Another option to try is the square root. The point is that with an exponential cost in the code length, the answer is to keep all of the code lengths the same, unless there is a huge difference in frequencies. So flattening the frequency distribution before computing the codes should give results that are close to the optimal.

Comment: @greybeard updated, all the same items share the same code, so both are OK.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks! You're right, in my condition, the difference among frequencies are huge. And sadly I cannot flatten that. I'll try some solutions. If any existing proved solution, that's best.

Comment: @user3386109 Updated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

China has extended the Spring Festival holiday because of the coronavirus outbreak in Wuhan. So I reviewed this need in my spare time.

I found some papers about this problem and wrote a [note](http://readm.tech/2020/02/03/huffman/)(in Chinese but you can use google translate) and [sample code](https://github.com/Readm/huffmanX) in python.

The paper is: Parker, Jr D S. Conditions for optimality of the Huffman algorithm[J]. SIAM Journal on Computing, 1980, 9(3): 470-489.

In short, the paper discussed what if the weight of the parent is not the sum of children(F(x,y)=x+y). Concluding that if the Function is **quasilinear** (with some requirements), the original Huffman algorithm will still produce the binary tree with the lowest root weight.

In my case, we need to define `F(x,y)=2(x+y)`, and everything goes OK.